Is there a good or commonly accepted short notation for the set of differentiable, but not necessarily continuously differentiable maps?
Every once in a while I find myself in need of some short notation for the set of differentiable, but not continuously differentiable maps, say, $X \to Y$. Always having to specify "differentiable, but not necessarily continuously differentiable" is rather inefficient to say the least.
Surely, I can't be the first one in the history of mathematics to be faced with the same problem!
It is quite standard to denote by $C(X,Y)$ or $C^0(X,Y)$ the space of continuous maps and by $C^k(X,Y)$, $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty,\omega\}$, the space of $k$-times continuously differentiable (resp. smooth or analytic) maps.

But is there somewhat accepted / standard notation for the set between $C^0$ and $C^1$ of differentiable, but not necessarily continuously so maps?

I guess, some possibilities are $C^{>0}(X,Y)$, $C^{0^+}(X,Y)$, or $C^{1^-}(X,Y)$, but it feels like I'm just making up stuff at this point (and chances are these notations already mean some other kinds of regularity stronger than $C^0$, but weaker than $C^1$).

I don't think I have seen a standard notation for these spaces. Note that especially the script +/- notation is in use in some sources for lipschitz maps

I have never seen any notation for this set either, it is a strange, pathologically behaved set of functions.

@NateRiver: You are right, the general pathology of such functions is likely the reason why there isn't a well established notation for this set. Nevertheless, in the presence of additional structure assuming such regularity can actually make sense, e.g. Looman–Menchoff theorem.

@AlexanderSchmeding: yes, that is one of the things I was afraid of.

There is a certain famous PDE where this is the natural class of functions too, but I am keeping that a research secret :P @M.G.

Since continuous functions use $C$, perhaps differentiable functions should use $D$, or the same character in some other font?   While it wouldn't be an accepted notation it would be a small variation on a standard for notation.

@RyanBudney: cool idea! I wonder, however, if it might conflict with other standard space notations in analysis. The only one coming to mind right now would be spaces of test functions and distributions, but these are usually denoted by fancier $\mathcal{D}$-s.

I suppose you could go to other languages as well.  I'm assuming you are talking about Frechet-differentiable functions, so you could use $F$ in a stylized font, as well.
